# How to log any changes on @Entity automatically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to define an `@Entity` whose changes (CRUD operations) should be logged to a textfile.
Is there any framework I could use in conjunction with `spring`?

I know about `Envers`, but that would greate historical entries in a database table. But I just would like to have a logging, no version tracking.

I'm using mostly the spring `CrudRepository` interfaces for CRUD operations.

Comment: are those jpa entities?

Comment: yes they are jpa entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look into [JPA EntityListeners](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/24/jpa-entitylisteners/) which can log jpa lifecycles.

You can either annotate [lifecycle callback methods](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/23/jpa-lifecycle-callback-methods/) in the same class as below

**Using lifecycle callback methods**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@TableGenerator(name = "employee_gen", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_val", allocationSize = 1,table="id_gen")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "employee_gen", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int idEmployee;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int salary;

public int getIdEmployee() {
    return idEmployee;
}

public void setIdEmployee(int idEmployee) {
    this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
}

// gettrs and setters

@PrePersist
public void methodInvokedBeforePersist() {
    System.out.println("Invoked before persisting employee");
}

@PostPersist
public void methodInvokedAfterPersist() {
    System.out.println("Invoked after persisting employee");
}

@PreUpdate
public void methodInvokedBeforeUpdate() {
    System.out.println("Invoked before updating employee");
}

@PostUpdate
public void methodInvokedAfterUpdate() {
    System.out.println("Invoked after updating employee");
}

@PreRemove
public void methodInvokedBeforeRemove() {
    System.out.println("Invoked before removing employee");
}

@PostRemove
public void methodInvokedAfterRemove() {
    System.out.println("Invoked after removing employee");
}

  }
```

**Using separate EntityListener classes**
Consider you have Employee entity for which you want to listen its lifecycle

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(EmployeeLoggingListener.class)
public class Employee{...}
```

and **EmployeeLoggingListerner** is as follows

```
public class EmployeeLoggerListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void methodInvokedBeforePersist(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("persisting employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee());
    }

    @PostPersist
    public void methodInvokedAfterPersist(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("Persisted employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void methodInvokedBeforeUpdate(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("Updating employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee());
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void methodInvokedAfterUpdate(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("Updated employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee());
    }

    @PreRemove
    private void methodInvokedBeforeRemove(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("Removing employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee());
    }

    @PostRemove
    public void methodInvokedAfterRemove(Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("Removed employee with id = " + emp.getIdEmployee() );
    }

 }
```

Comment: And how can I make efficient diff of properties from inside @Pre* method to log only changes?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`Hibernate interceptors`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/events.html), it is useful when you have to react to an event related to persistence, the callbacks provided are

> - onSave – Called when you save an object, the object is not save into
>     database yet.
> - onFlushDirty – Called when you update an object, the
>     object is not update into database yet.
> - onDelete – Called when you delete an object, the object is not delete into database yet.
> - preFlush – Called before the saved, updated or deleted objects are committed to database (usually before postFlush).
> - postFlush – Called after the
>     saved, updated or deleted objects are committed to database.

[here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/) you can find an exemplery audit log implementation based on the Hibernate interceptor

Comment: this really does not help get the unmutated version from the database on which to perform the diff

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Listener.

Add to the base class (all your entities classes should extend) methods marked as e.g.
@PrePersist or @PostUpdate

and write your logging there

See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenerPreUpdate.htm) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html)